# Stripe payment error : Invalid string id

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am getting below error when I create a Stripe Charge

> Invalid string id: {"number"=>"401288******1881", "exp_month"=>"02",
>   "exp_year"=>"2015", "cvc"=>"***", "name"=>"Tahir Yasin",
>   "address_line1"=>"lorem ipsum dolar", "address_line2"=>"lorem ipsum
>   dolar", "address_zip"=>"5400", "address_state"=>"Punjab",
>   "address_country"=>"PK"}{"success":true,"error":false}

**Stripe Charge and Collecting Fee**

```
try {
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                'amount' => 500,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'card' => array(
                    'number' => '4012888888881881',
                    'exp_month' => '02',
                    'exp_year' => '2015',
                    'cvc' => '123',
                    'name' => 'Tahir Yasin',
                    'address_line1' => 'lorem ipsum dolar',
                    'address_line2' => 'lorem ipsum dolar',
                    'address_zip' => '5400',
                    'address_state' => 'Punjab',
                    'address_country' => 'PK',
                ),
                'description' => '#100000011, tahiryasin@test.com',
                "application_fee" => 5
         ), 'SECRET_KEY_OF_CUSTOMER_TAKEN_VIA_STRIPE_CONNECT'
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Further digging the stack trace shows

```
[error] => Array
            (
                [type] => invalid_request_error
                [message] => Invalid string id: {"number"=>"401288******1881", "exp_month"=>"02", "exp_year"=>"2015", "cvc"=>"***", "name"=>"Tahir Yasin", "address_line1"=>"lorem ipsum dolar", "address_line2"=>"lorem ipsum dolar", "address_zip"=>"5400", "address_state"=>"Punjab", "address_country"=>"PK"}
                [param] => card
            )
```

I thought this could be due to dummy card details but I injected my real card details but still same error.

Can anyone please look into and let me know what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you can not provide card details directly through the API when creating a charge with Stripe Connect. You have to create a token with [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) first and use this card token to create the charge.

As per the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started#managing-accounts):

> Note that we require Stripe.js for all applications—you won't be allowed to send credit card data directly from your server.

Comment: can we create card token using PHP?

Comment: No you can't, you have to go through the token generation on the front end/browser

Comment: I found a way to create token using PHP API https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_card_token

Comment: Stripe does not allow sending card details directly through the API unless you are PCI-compliant on your end: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Comment: How they find if a website is PCI Complaint or not?

Comment: They would contact you directly and ask you for a proof since you are using the API in a way that requires you to be PCI Compliant.